# Python package not finding Java installation

Tags: jvm, conda, java-home

I'm trying to use some python packages on a remote server that's running on Ubuntu. This library depends on a Java virtual machine to work, and when trying to import it I ran into this error:

```
JVMNotFoundException: No JVM shared library file (libjvm.so) found. Try setting up the JAVA_HOME environment variable properly.
```

The package already came with OpenJDK as a dependency when I installed it, but even putting its path (in this case, /home/(my name)/.conda/pkgs/openjdk-11.0.1-h516909a_1016/; I also tried using the path to the libjvm.so file directly) into JAVA_HOME, it still kept giving me the same error message. Is there anything else I'm supposed to do on top of this, or am I doing the wrong thing? I'm not used to working with Linux so I'm really at a loss here.